# Update object array without adding new properties from another object

Tags: javascript, spread

Is it possible to update only the existing property values of an object without adding new properties from another object?

Here is my example.

```
form = {name: '',email: ''};
data = {name: 'sample', email: 'sample@gmail.com', datofbirth: '6/2/1990' };

form = {...form, ...data};

console.log(form);
```

Result:

```
{"name":"sample","email":"sample@gmail.com","datofbirth":"6/2/1990"}
```

Expected Result:

```
{"name":"sample","email":"sample@gmail.com"}
```

I dont want the dateofbirth or any new property added on my form object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want, hope it helps

```js
const form = { name: '', email: '' };
const data = {
    name: 'sample',
    email: 'sample@gmail.com',
    datofbirth: '6/2/1990',
};
Object.keys(form).forEach(key => {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        form[key] = data[key];
    }
});
console.log(form);
```

Comment: A little shorter: `Object.keys(form).map(key=> form[key] = data[key]);`

Answer (score 0):

Only add the keys you want in the spread rather than the whole object

```
form = { ...form, name: data.name, email: data.email };
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the keys in `form` and generate a new object using `Object.assign` and `spread syntax`.

```js
const form = {name: '',email: ''},
      data = {name: 'sample', email: 'sample@gmail.com', datofbirth: '6/2/1990' },
      result = Object.assign(...Object.keys(form).map(k => ({[k] : data[k]})));
console.log(result);
```